# Errno 111: Connection refused only in python IDLE

Tags: python, linux, sockets

When I try to execute Python server socket program and client socket program (both running in same linux machine) in Linux terminal **I don't get any error**, server accepts connection and sends data to client successfully.

But when I execute the same programs in python IDLE I get "**[Errno 111] Connection refused**" error.

What is the difference in both execution?

I'm using `serversock.bind(('',port#))` in server
and in client i'm using `clientsock.connect(('localhost',port#))`

Server.py

```
import socket

serversock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
host = ''
print host
port = 5800
serversock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
serversock.bind((host,port))
serversock.listen(2)

try:
    while True:
        csock,addr = serversock.accept()
        print 'Recieved address from %s '% str(addr)
        csock.send('hello')
        csock.close()

except Exception,e:
    print e
```

client.py

```
import socket

 try:
   c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   host = 'localhost'
   port = 5800
   c.connect((host,port))
   data = c.recv(1024)
   print data

except Exception,e:
   print e

finally:
   c.close()
```

Answer (score 1):

Server side you must use:

```
serversock.bind(('',port#))    # binds to port
serversock.listen(5)           # actually listen to port and allow 5 incoming calls
conv = serversock.accept()     # accept first incoming call
```

The connection will only be accepted after the `listen` call, before it, you have only bound a socket, but have not declared that you were ready to accept incoming calls, so they are refused.

---

With added code, another possible error cause is that you close connection (server side) immediately after sending data. That is bad: the close condition can destroy the socket before the data has actually been sent.

You should use a [graceful shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738547(VS.85).aspx):

- server side:

  ```
  csock.send('hello')
  csock.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR) # shutdown the socket
  csock.read() # wait the close from peer
  csock.close()
  ```
- client side: you can leave the code as is in your use case you do not send anything to server, so when the client has finished reading it can safely close the socket

Anyway you should close  serversock when everything is finished

```
try:
    ...
except ...:
    ...
finally:
    serversock.close()
```

Comment: Hi, I have added all the calls as I said before, my question is different, when I execute in Linux terminal socket programming works but when execute the same server and client in python idle I get the above error

Comment: @sanyesh: you did not show the call to listen. Do you confirm that you call it server side *before* calling connect client side?

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta please find the program i have added in the question.

Comment: @sanyesh: you forget to close `serversock` in server code but that should not cause this error. How do you execute in IDLE?

Comment: If i close server object then it wont listen to other queued up clients right?   But that should not cause this error... I open both the script in python IDLE and then I press F5 which run the program.

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta what does socket.SHUT_WR does? and what should I edit in client side if it is sending data to server?

Comment: @sanyesh with code in my answer and the link I gave you should be able to understand what should be done client side. And Python Library Manual will explain the `shutdown` method better than I could...